# Check scopes of personal access token from GitLab

Tags: rest, gitlab, gitlab-api, personal-access-token

How can I check the scopes (permissions) of a personal access token from GitLab? Given a personal access token, get all the scopes permitted to this token.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. I believe you want to be able to determine scopes given an API token. This is not possible - there is no API for it. I assume there's a security concern, too, as you wouldn't necessarily want someone to be able to enumerate permissions given a token.

Answer (score 5):

As of 2022, it is not exactly possible to check the scopes of a given PAT (personal access token). It is however possible to [list the scopes of all PATs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/personal_access_tokens.html#list-personal-access-tokens) of the user behind the given token.

In other words, if the user behind the given token G has tokens T1 and T2, it is possible to check the scopes of T1 and T2, but it cannot reliably be determined whether G == T1 or G == T2, etc.

To print the scopes of the first non-revoked token using `curl` and `jq`:

```
$ GITLAB_TOKEN="glpat-DefineYourOwn"
$ curl -sS -f -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/personal_access_tokens" | jq -j "map(select(.revoked == false)) | .[0].scopes | join(\" \")"
```

Sample output:

```
read_user read_api
```

Alas, the above command doesn't know the supplied token from the user's other tokens. It is possible to limit the choices further by also filtering on the name of a token:

```
"map(select((.revoked == false) and (.name == \"${EXPECTED_TOKEN_NAME_VAR}\")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can now get all the  permission of a specific token with the help of api

---

> GET /personal_access_tokens/self

---

mentioned in the gitlab docs

[GitLab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/personal_access_tokens.html#using-a-request-header)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature is not available at the moment with GitLab. If this is self managed instance you can still find that from backend/console but for GitLab.com this feature is not available. The best you can do here is to try the current defined scopes like `read_user`, `API`,`read_registry`,`sudo` GitLab 10.2 Allows performing API actions as any user in the system (if the authenticated user is an admin).`read_repository`, `write_repository` with your existing token.

Also this sounds like a fair request. Please consider creating a feature proposal for this [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues)