# Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/": unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I want to check if a container on gitlab is built properly with the right content. As a first step, I'm trying to login to the registry by running the following command:

`sudo docker login -u "ci-registry-user" -p "some-token" "registry.gitlab.com/some-registry:container"`

However, I run into `Get "https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/": unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied` errors.

My question is in two folds:

1. How do I access the hosted containers on gitlab? My goal is to access the container and run `docker exec -it container_name bash && cat /some/path/to_container.py`
2. Is there an alternative way to achieve this without logging in to the registry?

Answer (score 2):

Check your [GitLab PAT scope](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#personal-access-token-scopes), to make sure it is `API` or at least `read_registry`.

> Read-only (pull) for Container Registry images if a project is private and authorization is required.

And make sure you have access to that project with that token, if [`thesekyi/paalup`](https://gitlab.com/thesekyi/paalup) is a private project.

Avoid `sudo`, as it changes your environment execution from your logged-in user to `root`.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971539/check-scopes-of-personal-access-token-from-gitlab) says this feature is no more available. Do you know any other way I can check my PAT scope?

Comment: @theSekyi In that case, it is best, for testing, to create a new PAT with the right scope.